# prg pattern with php

Tags: php

how can i use prg pattern in php.please give me some example

Comment: Your last attempt was closed as "not a real question" because you failed to explain what you were trying to do, and what had failed about that attempt.  **You haven't even defined what "prg pattern" is**, and our guesses may be wrong.  You're going to need to provide more information -- and soon -- or this question will also be closed because it is not answerable.

Comment: It is simple: **More information => better answers**. Do yourself a favour and be more clear about your problem.

Comment: What is "prg"? [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)? A misspelling of [`preg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)? /confused

Answer (score 2):

if you want to know about the PRG (POST REDIRECT GET) pattern you can see this [PRG pattern](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/php-general@lists.php.net/8207403.html)